# Scraping with a multithreaded queue + urllib3 suffers a drastic slowdown

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, web-scraping, queue, urllib3

I am trying to scrape a huge number of URLs (approximately 3 millions) that contains JSON-formatted data in the shortest time possible. To achieve this, I have a Python code (python 3) that uses Queue, Multithreading and Urllib3. Everything works fine during the first 3 min, then the code begins to slow down, then it appears to be totally stuck. I have read everything I could find on this issue but unfortunately the solution seems to requires a knowledge which lies far beyond me.

I tried to limit the number of threads : it did not fix anything. I also tried to limit the maxsize of my queue and to change the socket timeout but it did no help either. The distant server is not blocking me nor blacklisting me, as I am able to re-launch my script any time I want with good results in the beggining (the code starts to slow down at pretty random time). Besides, sometimes my internet connection seems to be cut - as I cannot surf on any website - but this specific issue does not appear every time.

Here is my code (easy on me please, I'm a begginer):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib3,json,csv
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

csvFile =  open("X.csv",  'wt',newline="")
writer  =  csv.writer(csvFile,delimiter=";")
         writer.writerow(('A','B','C','D'))

def do_stuff(q):
    http = urllib3.connectionpool.connection_from_url('http://www.XXYX.com/',maxsize=30,timeout=20,block=True)

    while True:

        try:

            url = q.get()
            url1 = http.request('GET',url)      

            doc = json.loads(url1.data.decode('utf8'))

            writer.writerow((doc['A'],doc['B'], doc['C'],doc['D']))

        except:
             print(url)

        finally:
            q.task_done()

q = Queue(maxsize=200)
num_threads = 15

for i in range(num_threads):
    worker = Thread(target=do_stuff, args=(q,))
    worker.setDaemon(True)
    worker.start()

for x in range(1,3000000):
    if x < 10:
        url = "http://www.XXYX.com/?i=" + str(x) + "&plot=short&r=json"
    elif x < 100:
        url = "http://www.XXYX.com/?i=tt00000" + str(x) + "&plot=short&r=json"
    elif x < 1000:
        url = "http://www.XXYX.com/?i=0" + str(x) + "&plot=short&r=json"
    elif x < 10000:
        url = "http://www.XXYX.com/?i=00" + str(x) + "&plot=short&r=json"
    elif x < 100000:
        url = "http://www.XXYX.com/?i=000" + str(x) + "&plot=short&r=json"
    elif x < 1000000:
        url = "http://www.XXYX.com/?i=0000" + str(x) + "&plot=short&r=json"
    else:
        url = "http://www.XXYX.com/?i=00000" + str(x) + "&plot=short&r=json"

    q.put(url)

q.join()    
csvFile.close()
print("done")
```

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code. It's quite likely the server you're hammering is throttling/blocking your connections. Make sure you're respecting robots.txt and have reasonable ratelimiting or have an explicit SLA with the site for crawling it. Otherwise, to work around automated throttling, you'll probably need to crawl from many IP addresses.

Comment: Do you think implementing a sleep time in do_stuff() would be enough? If yes, how long will allow me to end my crawling smoothly, in your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

As shazow said, it's not the matter of threads, but timeouts at which each thread is getting data from server. Try to include some timout in your code:

```
finally:
    sleep(50)
    q.task_done()
```

it also could be improved by generating adaptive timeouts, for example You could measure how much data you successfully got, and if that number decreases, increase sleep time, and vice versa

Comment: That's pretty interesting. I will monitor the data I get over a 1 minute period/per thread. If that number decrease the thread will sleep for a number of secs * the number of time it has already slept (thus the sleeping time will be incremented depending on the performance of the thread - if necessary) - else it will continue its work and reset the number of pause to one.

Comment: @lo-bellin, I think it wouldn't much affect performance to chose lower interval, for example 5 sec. Functions `perf_counter` and `process_time` have been added to _time_ library, they have great accuracy.
For example, algorithm could calculate sleep time using formula sleep_t = const / (took2 - took1), so that it would deal with something like derivative of time taken to process(which is exactly the execution speed). That way algorithm should be flexible.

Comment: I believe we got to the "knowledge which lies far beyond me" thing. Would you mind provinding me a slightly more concrete example, please? Because I don't understand how "sleep_t = const / (took2 - took1)" will ensure that the sleep time is sufficient for the code not to hammer the website –

Comment: @LoBellin, in that formula took2 is current processing time and took1 is previous. It's better explained in pure mathematic terms: data transfer speed is the derivative(by time) of data amount transfered(bytes), Speed = dData / dT. Because you cant calculate derivative directly, it could be approximately replaced by deltas: Speed  ≈ ΔData / ΔT. It could be calculated using two points (Data2, t2) and (Data1, t1), which gives you Speed  ≈ (Data2 - Data1) / (t2 - t1), where Data1 and Data2 is amount of total bytes transfered at time t2 and t1

Comment: @LoBellin, because it seems better to measure bytes amount at one period(for example each 5 sec), this gives you times like: 0 sec (start), 5 sec (first fetch), 10 sec (second fetch) and so on, so for the first value of derivative (Speed) it would be Speed1 ≈ (Data2 - Data1) / (5 - 0), for second Speed2 ≈ (Data3 - Data2) / (10 - 5) and so on. Here you can see that divider is constant (at this example it's 5)

Comment: @LoBellin, the next thing is how should sleep time depend on transfer speed. The answer is simple: the lower the speed - the higher the sleep time should be: SleepTime_i = SomeConst / Speed_i, where i - current iteration number. That could be rewritten, using formula for speed:
SleepTime_i = SomeConst *  TimeConst / (Data_i - Data_[i-1] ), where TimeConst is our 5 sec for current example, SomeConst should be chosen experimentally

Comment: @LoBellin, and finally we could simplify our formula by including these two constants in one: SleepTime_i = Const / (Data_i - Data_[i-1] ). That gives the next algorithm: 1. Chose time interval, for example 5 sec; 2. Each 5 sec get current data amount transfered; 3. Write previous value of Data2 to Data1, and current amount to Data2; 4. Return SleepTime; 5. repeat step 2

Comment: @LoBellin, and this is how it may look like in Python: http://pastebin.com/Kf2e1Q0e
Also notice, that because we calculate the derivative, it could be <0, so one approach is to take its absolute value. Another pitfall is that you should avoid dividing by zero, for example in that case you could return some maximum sleep time value

Comment: @LoBellin, also notice that there are better approaches to calculating the derivative. For example, you could build a parabola ontop of 3 data points and take its derivative as approximation. Also the formula defining the relation between sleep time and speed could be improved using more complicated functions( now it uses parabola aka y = 1 / x)

Comment: That is really interesting. I'm gonna implement this in my code. Thanks a lot sir.